# Assign unique key values to each element pipelined RDD

Tags: pyspark, jupyter-notebook, bigdata, rdd

I have a pipelinedRDD:

```
districts.take(5)
['004', '022', '008', '003', '001']
```

I want each element to have a unique key like:

```
[(1,'004'), (2, '022'), etc....]
```

How do I do this?

Comment: rdd.zipWithIndex()

Answer (score 0):

use zipWithIndex() to add index to the rdd.

```
districts=sc.parallelize(['004', '022', '008', '003', '001'])
districts=districts.zipWithIndex()
districts.take(5)

[('004', 0), ('022', 1), ('008', 2), ('003', 3), ('001', 4)]
```

now use map to switch the position of value and index

```
districts=districts.map(lambda (x,y):(y,x))
districts.take(5)
[(0, '004'), (1, '022'), (2, '008'), (3, '003'), (4, '001')]
```